services is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:mockup" cannot list resource "services" in API group "" in the namespace "default"
I have this Helm chart which is used to deploy kubernetes pod:
https://github.com/rcbandit111/mockup/tree/master/helm_chart/mockup-chart
When I start the pod I get error:
2024-04-01 17:42:45.953 ERROR 1 --- [els.V1Service-1] i.k.c.informer.cache.ReflectorRunnable   : class io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1Service#Reflector loop failed unexpectedly

io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException: class V1Status {
    apiVersion: v1
    code: 403
    details: class V1StatusDetails {
        causes: null
        group: null
        kind: services
        name: null
        retryAfterSeconds: null
        uid: null
    }
    kind: Status
    message: services is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:mockup" cannot list resource "services" in API group "" in the namespace "default"
    metadata: class V1ListMeta {
        _continue: null
        remainingItemCount: null
        resourceVersion: null
        selfLink: null
    }
    reason: Forbidden
    status: Failure
}
        at io.kubernetes.client.util.generic.KubernetesApiResponse.lambda$throwsApiException$0(KubernetesApiResponse.java:64) ~[client-java-13.0.2.jar!/:na]
        at io.kubernetes.client.util.generic.KubernetesApiResponse.onFailure(KubernetesApiResponse.java:78) ~[client-java-13.0.2.jar!/:na]
        at io.kubernetes.client.util.generic.KubernetesApiResponse.throwsApiException(KubernetesApiResponse.java:62) ~[client-java-13.0.2.jar!/:na]
        at io.kubernetes.client.informer.SharedInformerFactory$2.list(SharedInformerFactory.java:254) ~[client-java-13.0.2.jar!/:na]
        at io.kubernetes.client.informer.cache.ReflectorRunnable.run(ReflectorRunnable.java:88) ~[client-java-13.0.2.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:358) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]

How I can configure this helm chart so that pod can access Kubernetes API?

It looks like you need to configure some roles and rolebindings for the mockup ServiceAccount. The RBAC documentation is probably a good place to start.

Yes I tried to add this: https://github.com/rcbandit111/mockup/blob/master/helm_chart/mockup-chart/templates/role.yml  But it's not working.

That's a role, which defines a set of permissions, but you need a rolebinding in order to attach those permissions to a serviceaccount.

Can you show me how to add this configuration to the helm chart please? By the way I use Kubernetes v1.29.2

I already have this role binding here :https://github.com/rcbandit111/mockup/blob/master/helm_chart/mockup-chart/templates/rolebinding.yml

But that rolebinding is for a serviceaccount sa-secret, and the error in your question is for serviceaccount mockup. I think spending some quality time with the RBAC documentation to which I linked in an earlier comment would be a good use of your time.
